# Refactoring “staircasing” with case of `Maybe` values in `IO` code

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type, io-monad

The following function `f` attempts to read an `Int` twice by using an `IO (Maybe Int)` function twice, but “short-circuits” execution after successfully reading one `Int`:

```
readInt :: IO (Maybe Int)

f :: IO (Maybe Int)
f = do
  n1 <- readInt
  case n1 of
      Just n' -> return (Just n')
      Nothing -> do
        n2 <- readInt
        case n2 of
              Just n' -> return (Just n')
              Nothing -> return Nothing
```

Is there a good way to refactor this code? This would get very hairy if I extended it to three attempts…

(My thought process: Seeing this “staircasing” tells me that maybe I should be using the `Monad` instance of `Maybe`, but since this is already in the `IO` monad, I would then have to use `MaybeT`(?). However, I only need *one* of the `readInt` to succeed, so the `Maybe` monad's behaviour of erroring out on the first `Nothing` would be wrong here...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `MaybeT` and the `MonadPlus` instance to use `msum`:

```
f :: MaybeT IO Int
f = msum [readInt, readInt, readInt]
```

Comment: Perhaps clarify for the benefit of others that he'd have to wrap the `IO (Maybe Int)` computation in the `MaybeT` constructor

Answer (score 4):

You need the alternative instance for `MaybeT`:

```
instance (Functor m, Monad m) => Alternative (MaybeT m) where
    empty = mzero
    (<|>) = mplus

instance (Monad m) => MonadPlus (MaybeT m) where
    mzero = MaybeT (return Nothing)
    mplus x y = MaybeT $ do
        v <- runMaybeT x
        case v of
            Nothing -> runMaybeT y
            Just _  -> return v
```

I.e. compute the first argument and return the value if it's `Just`, otherwise compute the second argument and return the value.

The code:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Text.Read

readInt :: MaybeT IO Int
readInt = MaybeT $ readMaybe <$> getLine 

main = runMaybeT (readInt <|> readInt) >>= print
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```
n2 <- readInt
case n2 of
      Just n' -> return (Just n')
      Nothing -> return Nothing
```

is really just `readInt`. You are picking apart a `Maybe` value in order to put together the same one.

For the rest, I think the most succinct way in this case is to use the `maybe` function.  Then you can get just

```
f = maybe readInt (return . Just) =<< readInt
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is with the [iterative monad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.10.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Iter.html) from the `free` package.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Iter (untilJust,retract,cutoff,IterT)

readInt :: IO (Maybe Int)
readInt = undefined

f' :: IterT IO Int
f' = untilJust readInt

f :: IO (Maybe Int)
f = (retract . cutoff 2) f'
```

Where [`cutoff`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.10.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Iter.html#v:cutoff) specifies the maximum number of retries.

The advantage of this approach is that you can easily [interleave other repeated actions](https://gist.github.com/danidiaz/e9382127d1c4025b9845) with `f'`, thanks to the `MonadPlus` instance of `IterT`. Logging actions for example, or wait actions.